# PowerShell ISE 'NuGet-anycpu.exe is required to continue' error and PowerShell ISE closes immediately after opening

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

All of a sudden my PowerShell ISE is stopped working. PowerShell ISE and PowerShell ISE (x86) are being closed immediately after I opened them. I have not done any changes to PowerShell ISE documents as well. Right after opening I see the following error message and I managed to take a screenshot before it was closed.

[image: error message]

I am using Windows 10 and PSVersion is 5.1.1. Can anybody help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue after reading a long thread [here](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/166). The issue was solved by some guys there but I had to combine some threads to get the complete solution.

First I needed to enable Module Browser for 64-bit version of PowerShell ISE.

1. Open PowerShell profile script which resides here `%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` for editing. It should be something like `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile`.
2. Copy Paste following lines after the commentary header

.

```
If ($env:PSModulePath.Split(';') -contains "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -and ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess)) {
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ISEModuleBrowserAddon\1.0.1.0\ISEModuleBrowserAddon.dll'
Write-Host 'Loaded 64-bit version'
} else {
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Module Browser\ModuleBrowser.dll'
Write-Host 'Loaded 32-bit version'
}
```

3. Comment-out lines starting with `$moduleBrowser = ....` and `$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab...`
4. Save your changes and exit.
5. If ISEModuleBrowser does not exist in Program Files then install it through PowerShell Command App (this has a dark blue logo, it is not the ISE) by using the following command `Install-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon`

These steps helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This still works for the issue in ISE.

Of note is that after running **Install-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon** that the **ISEModuleBrowser** is not in Program Files itself, but rather is found in **C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules**.